# Jquery Range Slider - Creating Tooltip that shows Range Slider Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a range slider that shows the user banner sizes visually while also giving them the price of the banner to purchase. I have an array set up that displays the sizeRange within a div. 
https://codepen.io/stinkytofu3311/pen/GmKxoW

```
var sizeRange = ["11x17 - Starting Price <span>$19.99</span>",

        "24x36 - Starting Price <span>$29.99</span>",

        "70x90 - Starting Price <span>$39.99</span>",

        "120x50 - Starting Price <span>$49.99</span>",

        "67x18 - Starting Price <span>$59.99</span>",

        "19x30 - Starting Price <span>$69.99</span>"]
```

Does anybody know how i could place the value inside of a tooltip that then would follow the slider while the user moves it right to left?

Here is a visual example..
[image]

Comment: You've done the heavy portion of what you needed to achieve! Don't give up on this one! You already have a DIV that contains all the information you need, the only thing you need is to move that div (and apply some CSS to create an arrow) where the drag element is at only when it is moved (you even have the two functions needed!) Let me know if you need an example.

Comment: Thank you for the encouragement. I'm a designer, pretending i can code to finish a project. :p  I definitely can style it to look like the tool-tip with CSS, i guess the real problem is how would i allow the div to follow the slider?

Comment: Would it be absolutely positioned some how based on the range-sliders thumb location?

Comment: Does that work? Or at least help you in the right direction?

Comment: Do you have a link by chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is my first attempt to do what you need. Given that you are a designer you will be able to style it much better than I can do :)

```
[![var moveit = false;
var sizeRange = \["11x17 - Starting Price <span>$19.99</span>",

        "24x36 - Starting Price <span>$29.99</span>",

        "70x90 - Starting Price <span>$39.99</span>",

        "120x50 - Starting Price <span>$49.99</span>",

        "67x18 - Starting Price <span>$59.99</span>",

        "19x30 - Starting Price <span>$69.99</span>"\]


var imageUrl = new Array(); // Store images inside of an Array

        imageUrl\[0\] = 'http://svgshare.com/i/1Ak.svg';

        imageUrl\[1\] = 'http://svgshare.com/i/1AQ.svg';

        imageUrl\[2\] = 'http://svgshare.com/i/1Bb.svg';

        imageUrl\[3\] = 'http://svgshare.com/i/1Am.svg';

        imageUrl\[4\] = 'http://svgshare.com/i/1CG.svg';

        imageUrl\[5\] = 'http://svgshare.com/i/1By.svg';


$('#sliderPrice').html( sizeRange\[0\] );

$(document).on('input change', '#range-slider', function() { //Listen to slider changes (input changes)
    var v=$(this).val(); //Create a Variable (v), and store the value of the input change (Ex. Image 2 \[imageURL\])

   $('#sliderStatus').html( $(this).val() );
   $('#sliderPrice').html( sizeRange\[v\] );

  $("#img").prop("src", imageUrl\[v\]); // Modify the Images attribute src based on the sliders value, and input the value inside the imageURL\[v\] to display image
});

// ::::: Range Slider Thumb ::::: //

$("#range-slider").on("mousedown", function() { //1. When user clicks their mouse down on the Range-Slider
    $(this).removeClass().addClass("thumb-down");//1.1 Remove default class from CSS, and add the class .thumb-down (changes background color)
    $(this).addClass("hover-ring");//1.2 Remove default class from CSS, and add the class .hover-ring (changes box-shadow to a green color)
  moveit = true;
});

$("#range-slider").on("mouseup", function() { //2. When user mouse-up on Range-Slider

    $(this).addClass("thumb-up"); //2.1 Changes thumb color back to light green

    $(this).addClass("hover-ring-out"); //2.2 Removes Box-Shadow
  moveit = false;
});


  $(document).mousemove(function(e){      
            var parentOffset = $('#range-slider').parent().offset(); 
            var relX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
            var relY = e.pageY - parentOffset.top;        
            $('#sliderPrice').css('top', relY).css('left', relX);
      });][1]][1]
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JNPvEJ

Comment: I just saw this! That's great. 

There seems to be an issue with it lagging behind when you slide to the left once you go right. Thanks so much! This will help me a lot in solving this thing.

Comment: Great! Yeah, as I said, is not great but it is the best I can do right now, if this helped you, please, vote the answer as it will help me. Thanks!